# "Default member initializer needed within definition of enclosing class outside of member functions" - is my code ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

```
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
    int x{0};
    foo() noexcept = default;
    void f() noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<foo&>())) {}
};

int main()
{ 
}
```

[**live example on godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/g/6RcGxn)

---

The code above compiles with any version of g++ I tested, and with clang++ from 3.6 to 3.9.1, but **does not compile with clang++ 4.0.0**:

```
test.cpp:6:5: error: default member initializer for 'x' needed within 
definition of enclosing class 'foo' outside of member functions
    foo() noexcept = default;
    ^
type_traits:126:26: note: in instantiation of template 
class 'std::is_function<foo &>' requested here
    : public conditional<_B1::value, _B1, __or_<_B2, _B3, _Bn...>>::type
                        ^
type_traits:154:39: note: in instantiation of template 
class 'std::__or_<std::is_function<foo &>,
    std::is_reference<foo &>, std::is_void<foo &> >' requested here
    : public integral_constant<bool, !_Pp::value>
                                    ^
type_traits:598:14: note: in instantiation of template 
class 'std::__not_<std::__or_<std::is_function<foo &>,
    std::is_reference<foo &>, std::is_void<foo &> > >' requested here
    : public __not_<__or_<is_function<_Tp>, is_reference<_Tp>,
            ^
type_traits:121:26: note: in instantiation of template 
class 'std::is_object<foo &>' requested here
    : public conditional<_B1::value, _B1, _B2>::type
                        ^
type_traits:635:14: note: in instantiation of template 
class 'std::__or_<std::is_object<foo &>,
    std::is_reference<foo &> >' requested here
    : public __or_<is_object<_Tp>, is_reference<_Tp>>::type
            ^
type_traits:1667:33: note: in instantiation of template 
class 'std::__is_referenceable<foo &>' requested here
template<typename _Tp, bool = __is_referenceable<_Tp>::value>
                                ^
type_traits:1678:14: note: in instantiation of default 
argument for '__add_rvalue_reference_helper<foo &>'
    required here
    : public __add_rvalue_reference_helper<_Tp>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
type_traits:2267:12: note: in instantiation of template 
class 'std::add_rvalue_reference<foo &>' requested
    here
    inline typename add_rvalue_reference<_Tp>::type
        ^
wtfff.cpp:7:32: note: while substituting explicitly-specified 
template arguments into function template 'declval'
    void f() noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<foo&>())) {}
                            ^
wtfff.cpp:5:9: note: default member initializer declared here
    int x{0};
        ^
```

**Is my code ill-formed?** If so, what's the meaning of the error?

Note that removing the `noexcept` from the constructor or the `{0}` initializer from `x` will make the code compile.

Comment: Within default member initializers, the enclosing class type is required to be complete, so they are only parsed once the enclosing class definition is complete. Apparently, something requires the default intializer already before the class was completely defined (I supposed " outside of member functions" is meant to say "outside contexts in which the class is considered completely defined"). Maybe the `= default` constructor?

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/45T3pNlh0PKAO2t5)

Comment: The spec says *"If a function that is explicitly defaulted is declared with a noexcept-specifier that does not produce the same exception specification as the implicit declaration ([except.spec]), then ... if the function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is defined as deleted;"* . And *"An exception specification is considered to be needed when: ... the exception specification is compared to that of another declaration"*

Comment: And the exception specification of an implicit declaration of that constructor is computed by evaluating the implicit definition of that constructor, which then necessiates the default member initializer's definition, which then necessiates the error message.

Comment: I don't see why clang gives such an instantiation backtrace into the Standard library though. It would seem that something else is going on, here.

Comment: [Reproduced without `#include <utility>`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/07VR8COte5f8YU2j)

Comment: It's enough to trigger *any* instantiation. It doesn't even need to mention `foo`, it just has to happen during a `noexcept` specification of the member function, it seems: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BJ4Ui1TXPtb1HIg9

Comment: Hm.. I think what I wrote above makes sense, but that can't be how things work, because then the class with simply the `x` and the defaulted constructor in it would be ill-formed. And that hasn't even touched on the issue how to find all later declared members, when it would have to immediately evaluate the implicit definition of that default constructor.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That's a crazy example. I really hope this is a clang bug, cause otherwise...

Comment: What is the purpose of `noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<foo&>()))` as opose to `noexcept(std::declval<foo&>())`, i.e., not nesting?

Comment: What is the point of `noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<foo&>()))`?  noexcept if calling a function with no body that returns a `foo&` is noexcept?  That seems like nonsense.

Comment: @Yakk: it's just a minimal example that reproduces the "weird" behavior.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code is fine from what I can tell.  Clang seems to struggle with the `= default` constructor rather than just defining a default constructor manually.  It has the following spiel in its source code about it:

> DR1351:
>     If the brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member
>     invokes a defaulted default constructor of its class or of an
>     enclosing class in a potentially evaluated subexpression, the
>     program is ill-formed.
>
> This resolution is unworkable: the exception specification of the
>   default constructor can be needed in an unevaluated context, in
>   particular, in the operand of a noexcept-expression, and we can be
>   unable to compute an exception specification for an enclosed class.
>
> Any attempt to resolve the exception specification of a defaulted default
>   constructor before the initializer is lexically complete will ultimately
>   come here at which point we can diagnose it.

I think it may be incorrectly picking up the error, personally.  But it specifially mentions "defaulted default constructor".

The following seems to work:

```
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
    int x{0};
    foo() noexcept {} // = default;
    void f() noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<foo&>())) {}
};

int main()
{ 
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, post revision, file, line where you have found this statement in clang?

Comment: Found it here: http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Sema/SemaDeclCXX.cpp?revision=305903&view=markup

Comment: Has this bug been reported with LLVM?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it might be related to this commit in November. https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20161121/177858.html

It *must* be a compiler bug.  Has it been reported?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is fine.

- Your `int x{0}` clearly falls under the category [non-static data member with initializer (C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class).
- The `declval` does not require a complete type--that's kind of the point of it, as explained in [this nice exposition](https://thenewcpp.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/decltype-and-declval/).

What's left? Compiler bug, I guess. How about this for evidence? Use a complete type `z` instead of `foo` in your `declval`.

```
#include <utility>
struct z{};
struct foo
{
    int x{0};
    foo() noexcept = default;
    void f() noexcept( noexcept( std::declval<z>() ) ) {}
};

int main()
{ 
}
```

[Clang 4.0.0 on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/AoFY5s) still errors the same way. Unfortunately I do not have clang 4.0.0 available on a machine to test, so I cannot not say whether it is Clang or godbolt for certain.

Comment: How can `noexecpt( std::declval<z>() )` make any *practical* sense?

Answer (score 0):

As C++ 11 standard states

> § 5.3.7
>
> The `noexcept` operator determines whether the evaluation of its operand, which is an **unevaluated operand**
>   (Clause 5), can throw an exception (15.1).
>
> ```
> noexcept-expression:
> noexcept ( expression )
> ```
>
> The result of the noexcept operator is a constant of type bool and is an rvalue.
>   The result of the noexcept operator is false if in a potentially-evaluated context the expression would
>   contain
>
> — **a potentially evaluated call to a function**, member function, function pointer, or member function
>   pointer that **does not have a non-throwing exception-specification** (15.4), unless the call is a constant
>   expression (5.19),
>
> — a potentially evaluated throw-expression (15.1),
>
> — a potentially evaluated dynamic_cast expression dynamic_cast(v), where T is a reference type,
>   that requires a run-time check (5.2.7), or
>
> — a potentially evaluated typeid expression (5.2.8) applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a
>   polymorphic class type (10.3).
>
> Otherwise, the result is true.

and

> ```
> template <class T>
> typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept; // as unevaluated operand
> ```

The `add_rvalue_reference` is of type Transformation Trait and, not explicitly said, but does not require object/function definition to be instantiated.

From here it is clear that `struct foo; ... noexcept(std::declval<foo>())` is a legal code. Where `noexcept` part, by the way, is equivalent to `noexcept(true)` that is equivalent to just `noexcept`, and `noexcept(noexcept` does not make sense, to get a constructor noexcept specifier you have to do this `noexcept(foo())`. The latter is valid as well, but, unfortunately, compilers are not able to deal with it, probably because of the order how they build the unit for non C++11 code, and they have not transformed this model yet. This reflects the nature of the bug that you encounter in the particular libc++ implementation. For some reasons `add_rvalue_reference` due to the presence of `noexcept` specifier tries to use declaration of the constructor and since that happens outside of the member function, as mentioned before, it fails. So yes, this is a bug of the library.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the library - you can replace the `declval` with any template instantiation and get the same error (e.g. `template <class T> struct X { }; ... noexcept(noexcept(X<int>{}))`)

Comment: Holy Christ, what can I say, did not go in this details, I just when through the libcxx and looked at the `add_rvalue_reference` implementation and did not find the same context that is in the question, and I thought that they decided to update the `type_traits` and they updated it with bugs. That was my guess. But seems it is much deeper. Anyway I think my answer might not be the best, but the point in it is that it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct syntactical way is I can say.

```
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
    int x{0};
    foo() noexcept {} // = default;
    void f() noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<foo&>())) {}
};

int main()
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this got fixed in clang 6: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fzsvhxaP8 (using litb's reduced repro from above).