# “Default member initializer needed within definition of enclosing class outside of member functions” - is my code ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, inner-classes, noexcept

```
struct foo
{
    struct bar {
        ~bar() {}                // no error w/o this line
    };
    bar *data = nullptr;         // no error w/o this line
    foo() noexcept = default;    // no error w/o this line
};
```

Yes, I know, there is another question with *exactly* the same title, but a somewhat different problem (involving a `noexcept` *operator* and no nested type). The solution suggested there (replacing the constructor of `foo` with

```
    foo() noexcept {}
```

) changes the semantics and it not necessary here: here we have a better answer (hence the question is not a duplicate).

compiler: `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)`, full error message:

```
test.cc:44:5: error: default member initializer for 'data' needed within definition of enclosing class 'foo' outside of member functions
    foo() noexcept = default;
    ^
test.cc:41:10: note: default member initializer declared here
    bar* data = nullptr;
         ^
```

Comment: You can just declarare the destructor in `bar` and define it out of the class. This way it compiles.

Comment: This is a clang bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Default member initializer needed within definition of enclosing class outside of member functions" - is my code ill-formed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819314/default-member-initializer-needed-within-definition-of-enclosing-class-outside)

Comment: @underscore_d Have you read my post? It seems you only read the title.

Answer (score 3):

This is a clang bug. But there is a simple workaround.

When one defines a special member function as defaulted, the `noexcept` specifier is just used to check that the defaulted special member generated by the compiler will be `noexcept`, [[dcl.sft.dcl.def]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#3):

> If a function that is explicitly defaulted is declared with a
>   *noexcept-specifier*
>   that does not produce the same
>   exception specification as the implicit declaration [(18.4)](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#3), then
>
> — if the function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is defined as deleted;
>
> — otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

So if you remove the noexcept sepcifier of `foo` default constructor, you will not change the semantic, `foo` will still be nothrow default constructible:

```
#include <type_traits>
struct foo
  {
  struct bar {
    ~bar() {}                // no error w/o this line
    };
  bar *data = nullptr;         // no error w/o this line
  foo()= default;    // foo is noexcept, weither the declarator contains noexcept or not
  };

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<foo>::value);
```

Comment: If this is a known clang but, then there must be a citable entry into the respective bug repository. Can you provide a link to that?

Comment: Actualy, this is defactor a clang bug because of the inconsitency of its behavior: it should not depend on the noexcept specifier if in both case the default constructor is noexcept. Why I will no check or fill a bug for clang? My conception of property followes the romanic right: a field belong to the one who farms it. So clang is the property of google and I am not going to work for free for them! You can do it if you want, this is not my business.

Comment: How wrong you are. Clang is open source and google is just one of the contributors, others include Apple, Microsoft, AMD, ARM, Sony, Intel.

Comment: If you demonstrate, for example using the standard, that my code is indeed well formed, I'm happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @Walter, I have added a citation. But this is probably not sufficiant. If you say me what are your doubts, I will add citations to the standard paragraph that will clear these doubts.

Comment: @Walter Speaking generally, it is sometimes (often?) the case that bugs do exist, but the people who complain about them only do so in unrelated venues, rather than reporting them to people who would be able to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by defaulting the destructor of the nested class

```
struct foo
{
    struct bar {
        ~bar() = default;        // this fixes it
    };
    bar *data = nullptr;         // no error w/o this line
    foo() noexcept = default;    // no error w/o this line
};
```

However, it's not clear to me why/whether this is required by the standard.

Comment: Added benefit of `~bar() = default;` vs `~bar() {}` : `~bar` is now trivial which it isn't when it's user defined (even if empty).