# Try to understand compiler error message: default member initializer required before the end of its enclosing class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I try next code with three compilers (msvc2017, gcc8.2, clang7.0) and msvc2017 works all the way, but gcc and clang not. I want to understand what is wrong with my code, and why compiler can't compile it.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Downloader
{
public:

    struct Hints
    {       
        int32_t numOfMaxEasyHandles = 8;
        //Hints(){}          // <= if I uncomment this all works gcc+clang+msvc
        //Hints() = default; // <= if I uncomment this neither clang no gcc works (msvc - works)
    };

    static Downloader *Create(const Hints &hints = Hints());
};

Downloader* Downloader::Create(const Hints &hints)
{
    std::cout << hints.numOfMaxEasyHandles << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

You can play with this code yourself on https://wandbox.org/ and see error:

```
prog.cc:16:58: error: default member initializer for 'Downloader::Hints::numOfMaxEasyHandles' required before the end of its enclosing class
     static Downloader *Create(const Hints &hints = Hints());
                                                          ^
prog.cc:11:37: note: defined here
         int32_t numOfMaxEasyHandles = 8;
                                     ^~~~
```

Why gcc and clang not compile this code even with uncomment `Hints() = default`?
My compile commands:

1. `$ g++ prog.cc -std=gnu++2a`
2. `$ clang++ prog.cc -std=gnu++2a`

But if I uncomment `Hints(){}` all three compilers works. Maybe it is compiler bug? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819314/default-member-initializer-needed-within-definition-of-enclosing-class-outside and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866686/default-member-initializer-needed-within-definition-of-enclosing-class-outside?rq=1

Comment: seems clang still struggles from that bug !!

Comment: @Serhii they look related but not exactly matching bugs, I found another bug report which seems to match pretty close to this case.

Comment: To make GCC and Clang diverge here, one can declare `noexcept = default` constructor in `Hints` and default argument `Create(const Hints &hints = {})`, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GGjKf34zv

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a clang and gcc bug, we have a [clang bug report for this: default member initializer for 'm' needed within definition of enclosing class for default argument of function](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36684) which has the following example:

```
#include <limits>
class A
{
   public:
      class B
      {
         public:
            explicit B() = default;
            ~B() = default;

         private:
            double m = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
      };

   void f(double d, const B &b = B{}) {}
};

int main()
{
   A a{};
   a.f(0.);
}
```

which produces the following similar diagnostic:

```
t.cpp(15,34):  error: default member initializer for 'm' needed within definition of enclosing class 'A' outside of member functions
   void f(double d, const B &b = B{}) {}
                                 ^
t.cpp(12,20):  note: default member initializer declared here
            double m = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
                   ^
```

Richard Smith indicates this is a bug:

> Regarding comment#0: if we want to fix this once-and-for-all, we should use the same technique we use for delayed template parsing: teach Sema to call back into the parser to parse the delayed regions on-demand. Then we would only reject the cases where there's an actual dependency cycle.

Although does not explain why in details.

Comment: I decide to add this bug to gcc too: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88165 (can't find match, so add new one)

Answer (score 10):

As of 2021 it's still not fixed, but as a work-around I'm using something like this:

```
namespace detail {
struct DownloaderHints
{       
    int32_t numOfMaxEasyHandles = 8;
};
}

class Downloader {
public:
    using Hints = details::DownloaderHints;
    static Downloader *Create(const Hints &hints = Hints());
};
```

Comment: FTR, still nothing in 2023 May (according to a quick test with the latest GCC and CLANG at godbolt.org).

Answer (score 9):

Here's my workaround:

```cpp
class Downloader
{
public:
    struct Hints
    {       
        int32_t numOfMaxEasyHandles = 8;
    };
    static Hints default_hints() { return {}; }
    static Downloader *Create(const Hints &hints = default_hints());
};
```

alternatively:

```cpp
...
    struct Hints
    {       
        int32_t numOfMaxEasyHandles = 8;
        static Hints Default() { return {}; }
    };
    static Downloader *Create(const Hints &hints = Hints::Default());
...
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/YMqzha3fP) it is on godbolt. This has the advantage of keeping `Hints` an aggregate, so we can still write:

```cpp
return Downloader::Create({
  .numOfMaxEasyHandles = 24,
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this to be the best workaround, since I really wanted to maintain support for designated initialization of the inner struct.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2022 the bug is still not fixed, but yet another workaround is to default a constructor in the .cpp file:

```
class Downloader
{
public:
    struct Hints
    {       
        int32_t numOfMaxEasyHandles = 8;
        Hints();
    };

    static Downloader *Create(const Hints &hints = Hints());
};

// In .cpp:

Downloader::Hints::Hints() = default;
```

Note however, that this prevents `Hints` from being an aggregate, which might e.g. prevent usage of dedicated initalizers.

Comment: The downside here is that `Hints` is no longer an aggregate so cannot use designated initializers.