# Why is my class non default-constructible?

Tags: c++, nsdmi

I have those classes:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<T>);

};

struct B {
   struct C {
      int i = 0;
   };

    A<C> a_m;
};

int main() {
    A<B::C> a;
}
```

When compiling, `a_m` is not default constructible but `a` is.

When changing `C` to:

```
struct C {
      int i;
   };
```

everything is fine.

Tested with Clang 9.0.0.

Comment: GCC 8.3 - OK, GCC 9.1/9.2 - Fail.

Comment: Workaround: Move the `static_assert` into a member function and it'll work: `A() {
        static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<T>);
    }` for exampe.

Comment: With `C() {}` it works, too.

Comment: This smells buggy to me. No immediately obvious match on Bugzilla.

Comment: Interesting: the `static_assert` in `A` fails, but if you instead default construct a `T` inside of `A` (e.g. put a member `T t;` there), it works all fine. An inconsistency between what the type trait is telling you and what is actually possible...

Comment: @sebrockm _std::is_default_constructible<T> does not test that T x;_ from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible).

Comment: FWIW, VS since 19.10 (or earlier) is happy

Comment: @Nicolas True, but that's because of some edge cases, none of which apply here (in particular, as the same sentence on cppreference says, `const int x;` is invalid without an initialiser, purely due to the `const` and the initialisation behaviour of built-in types and some history)

Comment: Couldn't [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible) be the clue: "If an instantiation of a template above [`std::is_default_constructible`] depends, directly or **indirectly**, on an **incomplete type**, and that instantiation could yield a different result if that type were hypothetically completed, the behavior is undefined."? `A<C>` depends indirectly on the incomplete type `B`.

Comment: @Evg How exactly does it depend on `B`? What hypothetical completion exists?

Comment: @MaxLanghof, `C` is a member type of `B`. Isn't that a dependence?

Comment: @Evg It still requires that there exists some hypothetical completion of `B` that gives a different result before the UB can be harnessed. By your quote, that is (have not looked at the standard).

Comment: @MaxLanghof, that's what bothers me, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is disallowed both by the text of the standard and by several major implementations as noted in the comments, but for completely unrelated reasons.

First, the "by the book" reason: the point of instantiation of `A<C>` is, according to the standard,  [immediately before the definition of `B`](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#4.sentence-2), and the point of instantiation of `std::is_default_constructible<C>` is immediately before that:

> For a class template specialization, [...] if the specialization is
>   implicitly instantiated because it is referenced from within another
>   template specialization, if the context from which the specialization
>   is referenced depends on a template parameter, and if the
>   specialization is not instantiated previous to the instantiation of
>   the enclosing template, the point of instantiation is immediately
>   before the point of instantiation of the enclosing template.
>   Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization
>   immediately precedes the namespace scope declaration or definition
>   that refers to the specialization.

Since `C` is clearly incomplete at that point, the behavior of instantiating `std::is_default_constructible<C>` is undefined. However, see [core issue 287](https://wg21.link/cwg287), which would change this rule.

---

In reality, this has to do with the NSDMI.

- NSDMIs are weird because they get delayed parsing - or in standard parlance they are a "complete-class context".
- Thus, that `= 0` could in principle refer to things in `B` not yet declared, so the implementation can't really try to parse it until it has finished with `B`.
- Completing a class necessitates the implicit declaration of special member functions, in particular the default constructor, as `C` doesn't have a constructor declared.
- Parts of that declaration (constexpr-ness, noexcept-ness) depend on the properties of the NSDMI.
- Thus, if the compiler can't parse the NSDMI, it can't complete the class.
- As a result, at the point when it instantiates `A<C>`, it thinks that `C` is incomplete.

This whole area dealing with delayed-parsed regions is woefully underspecified, with accompanying implementation divergence. It may take a while before it gets cleaned up.

Comment: I agree with the second part of this answer (the NSDMI), not sure about the first part (the "by the book" reason). I thought "point of instantiation" only affects dependent name lookup, but `is_default_constructible` doesn't need to look up any dependent names. We can observe the same problem without templates: https://godbolt.org/z/TGqYbd

Comment: @einpoklum that is just a link to this very question

Comment: @Oktalist: Sorry, I mis-copy-pasted. So, Would appreciate your input regarding NSDMI weirdness in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69050558/1593077).

Comment: @einpoklum I agree with the answers to your question. It doesn't follow that the class is complete just because the error message doesn't say it's not. Completeness of nested classes is complicated and subject to multiple open defects. It's the same issue as in this question. And also in https://stackoverflow.com/q/53408962/1639256

Answer (score 1):

[Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible) it is:

> If an instantiation of a template above depends, directly or
>   indirectly, on an incomplete type, and that instantiation could yield
>   a different result if that type were hypothetically completed, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Comment: Why is C incomplete?

Comment: @interjay, `C` is complete, but `B` isn't. And `B::C` depends indirectly on `B`.

Comment: @Evg The text "Depends directlly or indirectly" only appears on cppreference.com. The standard just says that the type T needs to be complete.

Comment: @T.C. Good find, looks like that text was added since C++17. It isn't clear to me what it means to "depend" on another type and whether that includes class nesting.

Comment: @interjay I wrote most of this wording. What we are trying to say is that 1) if you instantiate a trait in a way that could provoke an ODR violation later when some incomplete type is completed, that's undefined; and 2) it's undefined even if you don't _actually_ cause an ODR violation in your program, so that standard library implementations can choose to diagnose that at the point the trait is used if they so desire. If `C` has a default constructor template with some weird SFINAE that can change answers if `B` is completed differently, then sure, the trait depends on it.