# Why does default-constructibility behave weirdly for inner structs with NSDMI?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor, nsdmi

Consider the following code:

```c++
#include <type_traits>

struct outer {
    struct inner {
        unsigned int x = 0;
    };
//    static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<inner>::value,
//          "not default ctorable - inside");
};

static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<outer::inner>::value,
    "not default ctorable - outside");
```

This [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/snPf7Ks4W). But - if I uncomment the static assert inside `outer` - both asserts fail with clang++ and gcc++. Why should they not both pass?

Notes:

- The `inner` class is, in fact, complete, at the point of the first static assertion. The assertion does not fail due to incompleteness (a failure which produces a specific error message about incompleteness).
- Unlike in the related [Why is my class non default-constructible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252363/) , here - there are no templates, so there is no instantiation-before- the-definition.
- If you remove the initializer of `x` and enable the assertions, the code compiles. (This is also unlike the related question.)
- This:

  ```c++
  #include <type_traits>

  struct outer {
       struct inner {
           unsigned int x = 0;
       };

       inner get_an_inner() { 
           static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<outer::inner>::value,
               "not default ctorable - outside");
           return inner{}; 
       }
  };
  ```

  compiles!
- If we add an explicit default constructor, `constexpr inner() {}` - the program compiles.
- There's a [LLVM bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38374) about basically the same thing, but it's not just clang and the bug report has not gotten any comments.

**Updates:**

- Have submitted [GCC bug 102199](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102199) (against libstdc++).
- Have commented on the LLVM bug, let's see what happens there.

Comment: Not sure, but is `inner` a complete type before `outer` is?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I don't know what the standard says, but inner has been completely and fully specified. I don't see how it could make sense for it not to be recognized as default constructible. Also, I don't get an "incomplete type" error.

Comment: Me neither. I was trying to get a hint from [nested classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types) but couln't find any. Interesting question.

Comment: And if you put the `static_assert` inside your `get_an_inner()` function, it will also succeed.  Ted is correct, the issue is that `inner` isn't complete yet when you are trying to use it in `static_assert`.

Comment: As for why the file-level `static_assert` is affected, I assume that the failing `static_assert` inside the class disrupted compilation and prevented both `outer` and `outer::inner` from becoming complete.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But then, shouldn't I get an error about the incompleteness? Anyway, even if that's the case, the interesting part is the inner assert.

Comment: Check out the implementation of `static_assert`. I don't think it's supposed to go into a type declaration like that. If you keep both at namespace or function scope, it should work. Haven't tried that though, it's just my gut feeling.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: So, you're saying it's an imperfection in the implementations of static_assert? Interesting. But - static asserts often go into class definitions.

Comment: Last time I checked, `is_default_constructible` is a template. And in any event, the NSDMI explanation has nothing to do with templates anyway.

Comment: @T.C.: Well, there is no completeness problem for `is_default_constructible` here.

Answer (score 10):

The completeness status of member classes is **complicated**.  Because their member functions are allowed to do **forward** lookup into the surrounding class scope, those member functions are treated as not yet being **defined** when processing the (rest of) the containing class, despite the fact that the most basic notion of completeness is plainly **satisfied**:

```
struct A {
  struct B {};
  B b;          // OK
};
```

There are various open **issues** in this general area: [CWG2335](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2335) and [CWG1360](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1360), for instance.

Comment: This does not answer my question, actually. The problem isn't that the compiler  considers the class to be incomplete - the problem is that it considers it to be not default-constructible. If I add an explicit default constructor, the static assertions don't fai.

Comment: @einpoklum: Like so many do, the trait you’re using [depends on the type being complete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible).

Comment: The type is identified as complete. I've edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: @einpoklum: Didn’t I say that it was complicated, and that there are language defects here?

Answer (score 4):

First, why the inner static assert causes the outer static assert to fail? That's because templates are instantiated only once. Once `std::is_default_constructible<inner>::value` is `false`, it will remain `false`, even if default constructibility somehow changes. So the outer static_assert is not very interesting. Why does the inner static_assert fail?

In order to understand this, let's simplify this to the bare minimum. No templates or standard library!

```
struct outer {
    struct inner {
        unsigned int x = 0;
    };

    static constexpr inner i{};
};
```

This *fails* with a mysterious compiler message.

```
$ g++ -c dc.cpp 
dc.cpp:6:30: error: default member initializer for ‘outer::inner::x’ required before the end of its enclosing class
    8 |     static constexpr inner i{};
      |                              ^
dc.cpp:3:24: note: defined here
    5 |         unsigned int x = 0;
      |                        ^~~~


$ clang++  -c dc.cpp 
dc.cpp:6:30: error: default member initializer for 'x' needed within definition of enclosing class 'outer' outside of member functions
    static constexpr inner i{};
                             ^
dc.cpp:3:22: note: default member initializer declared here
        unsigned int x = 0;
                     ^
1 error generated.
```

So the compiler indeed cannot default-construct `inner` where needed, but why?

A quick search on the text of the error message yields [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408962/try-to-understand-compiler-error-message-default-member-initializer-required-be). The accepted answer classes it as a gcc and clang bug, but I'm not convinced. The clang bug report says "Then we would only reject the cases where there's an actual dependency cycle", but the standard doesn't seem to require dependency cycle detection anywhere. This could be a defect in the standard rather than a compiler bug.

Comment: So, you're claiming that GCC and clang's bug is in viewing `inner` as a complete type, while in fact it isn't?

Comment: Also, my code snippet becomes possible to compile when we add a (constexpr or otherwise) explicit, default constructor, while yours does not (even with a constexpr default constructor).

Comment: @einpoklum I am claiming no such thing. `inner i; static constexpr auto si = sizeof(inner);` compile OK. It is specifically initialisation that fails (either value initialisation or aggregate initialisation, I can never remember the difference), not any other odd thing that requires completeness.