# std::is_default_constructible returns the wrong value for a nested class, gcc bug or user error?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc12

`MyClass::MyData` appears to be default constructible, but `std::is_default_constructible_v<MyClass::MyData>()` returns false.  Is this a GCC bug?  Code on godbolt at https://godbolt.org/z/qrfz8c7h8.

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

class MyClass
{
public:
    
    struct MyData
    {
        // It doesn't matter if there is a default constructor here.
        MyData() = default;

        // Fix: Instead of using "= default", if you explicitly 
        // define an empty constructor everything works. (However,
        // eliminating the constructor altogether does not fix
        // the issue.)
        //MyData() { }

        const char* m_name{ nullptr };
    };


    std::variant<MyData> m_var;

    // Using this line instead will fix the problem.
    //std::variant<MyData> m_var{ MyData{} };

    // Or, commenting out this constructor will fix the problem.
    MyClass()
    {
    }
};

// Notice the inconsistency here.  I can clearly make a default x,
// but the static assert fails.
MyClass::MyData x;
static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<MyClass::MyData>);

MyClass y;
static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<MyClass>);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Note from original poster:** The duplicate shown does answer the question, although this is a slightly different case.

- The first time `std::is_default_constructible` is checked is when the variant is declared.
- At that time, the containing class is not fully declared, and so `std::is_default_constructible_v` is `false` (at least in gcc).
- When the static assert is checked later, the declaration is complete.  The class can now be default constructed, but unfortunately, `std::is_default_constructible_v` must stay the same and is still `false`.

It isn't completely clear to me whether this is a gcc bug (erroring on valid code) or a Microsoft bug (accepting invalid code), but the question is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: The static assert you point at does not in fact fail. Only the variant chokes, and that is touched upon in the dupe.

Comment: `MyData() noexcept = default;` and all's well

Comment: @TedLyngmo That makes sense.  However, if I don't put a constructor at all, the problem is there.  Here's a simplified godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/z716rr4KE.  It seems that the variant declaration screws up the class definition somehow?

Ok, I now see the dupe.  the variant declaration causes is_default_constructible_v() to be called prematurely and the value gets cached.

Comment: Clang also fails to compile this, MSVC accepts

Comment: Linked duplicate doesn't fit to this scenario. Please try different versions `0-2` https://godbolt.org/z/rr838xdcP (note moved default constructor outside) - so reopening.

Comment: Sigh... there will always be a busybody... posting the duplicate link again https://stackoverflow.com/q/69050558/817643

Comment: @MarekR in what way is that different than the duplicate? The duplicate seems spot on.

Comment: From the original poster, the cause is the same as the dupe.  I accept that.  I'll see if I can make an edit to clarify.