# Weird interaction among optional, nested classes and is_constructible

Tags: c++, c++17, inner-classes, type-traits

Working on a real-life project, I've stumbled across the weird behavior of some (versions of some) compilers. Consider the following class declaration(s):

```cpp
struct OptionalsStruct {
    struct InnerType {
        bool b{};
    };

    OptionalsStruct() = default;

    std::optional<InnerType> oInnerType;
};
```

For some compilers, you have that `OptionalStruct::InnerType` is *nothrow constructible* but not *constructible* or *default constructible* ([clang 11](https://godbolt.org/z/zMGG7eGca) to [16](https://godbolt.org/z/PhTWWPhY4) and [GCC 10](https://godbolt.org/z/M14v5M1o7)), for some other compilers it's neither *nothrow constructible* ([clang 9](https://godbolt.org/z/e67hPrWqK) and [10](https://godbolt.org/z/jPYj5s5G5)), not to mention how [clang 8](https://godbolt.org/z/jPYj5s5G5) sees the whole thing.

My question is: are these behaviors compiler bugs, or even *holes* in the standard (I'm using C++17)? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Side notes: results may vary wildly if you touch anything, like the explicit initialization of the member variable `b`, or the explicit `default` constructor for `OptionalsStruct`.

Comment: Adding a constructor to `InnerType` (non-`=default`) fixes this. I've seen this before in other scenarios (all involving nested classes), but never found an acceptable explanation.

Comment: Potentially duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252363/why-is-my-class-non-default-constructible. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408962/try-to-understand-compiler-error-message-default-member-initializer-required-be and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050558/why-does-default-constructibility-behave-weirdly-for-inner-structs-with-nsdmi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compilers don't consider `Inner` as "fully complete" until after the `}` of the outer-most enclosing class because the complete-class context rules require the compiler to delay lookup in the default member initializer for `b` until after that point, but certain properties of (implicit) declarations of special member functions of the enclosing class may indirectly depend on properties of the default member initializer.

With that interpretation you have undefined behavior for instantiating `std::optional` with an incomplete type as template argument.

Practically speaking, the instantiation of `std::optional` may cause instantiation of the type traits specializations you are using in `main`, depending on the `std::optional` implementation. If so, then the type trait specializations are instantiated with incomplete types, which also causes undefined behavior and practically can't produce sensible results.

Because class template specializations are instantiated only once (and the compiler can cache the result), your later use of the traits then depends on the nonsensical results of the previous implicit instantiations.

As far as I know it is an open defect in the standard that completeness of nested classes isn't well-specified and it is unclear whether the compiler's interpretation is the "correct" one.

(And from a very pedantic point of view it is UB per standard anyway, because the point of instantiation of `std::optional<InnerType>` would be before the namespace scope declaration causing the implicit instantiation, i.e. before `struct OptionalsStruct {`, where `InnerType` is certainly incomplete. See [CWG issue 287](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287).)

Comment: Since `InnerType oInnerType;` works as an `OptionalsStruct` member, `InnerType` is clearly complete at that point, I think?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think the compilers are doing something in-between considering it complete or incomplete in different circumstances. In general it can't be considered complete, because you can cause circular dependencies that way.

Comment: What kind of circular dependencies?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'll try to construct an explicit example that doesn't rely on template instantiation later, but see e.g. the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59276856/17732522). Because there is template instantiation involved here, the first part of that answer would also be a more precise answer to this question, since technically the UB reason here is that the point of instantiation of `std::optional<InnerType>` is before `struct OptionalsStruct { /*...*/ };` where `InnerType` is definitively incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59276856/2752075).

A compiler effectively processes each class in two passes. The member function bodies are handled in the second pass, that's why they can use other members declared below them (which have been seen during the first pass).

And evidently, the second pass over `InnerType` doesn't begin until the first pass over `OptionalsStruct` is finished.

Non-static data member initialziers are also handled in the second pass, this includes `b`'s `{}`. This means `InnerType`'s constructability isn't known during the first pass.

When `std::optional` tries to query the constructability during the first pass, the compilers report junk. They memoize the junk values, and will report them again when the same trait is queried, even if that happens after `OptionalsStruct` is fully defined.

The fix is to add a non-`=default` constructor to `InnerType`, to make its constructability known during the first pass.