# When is a nested class completely-defined?

Tags: c++

I found some strange behavior with nested classes. This occurs in gcc 13.1 and the newest clang. The given example compiles, see https://godbolt.org/z/xYGsoTEq8. In my expectations the class A should be default constructible. If the static assert inside the class T is removed, the class A is default constructible. But the check within the class makes it to not be default constructible.

Is this undefined behavior? I don't think so because class A is completely-defined. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#mem-6

```
#include <type_traits>

struct T final {
    struct A final{
        double a{};
    };
    // outcomment the static assert and the program does not compile, because the static assert in the main fails
    static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible_v<A>);
    A v{};
};

int main() {
    static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible_v<T::A>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: clang's error message mentions `std::is_default_constructible_v<T::A>` so I'd guess that it's `T` not being completely defined that is breaking things, once the template has been instantiated once with UB it then seems to return the incorrect value again the next time it's used

Comment: Demo showing [Alan is on right track](https://godbolt.org/z/9EP1YEz1z).

Comment: Seems to cover the same ground https://stackoverflow.com/q/75814971/817643