# What does the error about default member initializer needed means?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, default-constructor

I have a code that works fine in Visual Studio:

```
struct A
{
    struct P{ P() = default; int x = 1; };
    void foo( const P & = {} );
};
```

However both `gcc` and `clang` refuse to compile it with the error:

```
<source>:4:28: error: default member initializer for 'A::P::x' required before the end of its enclosing class
    4 |     void foo( const P & = {} );
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ja3c9zPMY

Could you please suggest what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Moving `P` outside of the class solves the issue [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3WajPM1dq).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try to understand compiler error message: default member initializer required before the end of its enclosing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408962/try-to-understand-compiler-error-message-default-member-initializer-required-be)