default member initializer for needed within definition of enclosing class outside of member functions
The following code
class A {
public:
    struct B {
        unsigned int b0 = 10;
        unsigned int b1 = 11;
    };
    A::B empty {};
    const A::B emptyConst {};
    static constexpr A::B emptyStaticConstexpr {};
};

compiled with g++ 10.3.1 and -std=c++17 gives
const.cpp:9:46: error: default member initializer for 'A::B::b0' required before the end of its enclosing class
    9 |  static constexpr A::B emptyStaticConstexpr {};
      |                                              ^
const.cpp:4:19: note: defined here
    4 |   unsigned int b0 = 10;
      |                   ^~~~~
const.cpp:9:46: error: default member initializer for 'A::B::b1' required before the end of its enclosing class
    9 |  static constexpr A::B emptyStaticConstexpr {};
      |                                              ^
const.cpp:5:19: note: defined here
    5 |   unsigned int b1 = 11;
      |                   ^~~~~

Other versions of gcc seem to give similar results.
I don't understand the error message. To me, the default initializer seems to be right there "before the end of its enclosing class". Furthermore - interestingly - if you add to B a member without a default initializer, it will not complain about that but only about those that do have a default initializer. What am I doing wrong?
I understand that I could specify the initializers as part of the declaration :
...
static constexpr B emptyStateConstexpr {
  .b0 = 10,
  .b1 = 11,
}
...

but I wouldn't want to have to write those values again as I already have written them out above.
Placing static constexpr A::B emptyStateConstexpr {} outside of class A removes the error.
This question is different from Try to understand compiler error message: default member initializer required before the end of its enclosing class in that I am trying to instantiate a static constexpr while they were defining a default constructor for B and then trying to use the constructor as default parameter in a static method.

because your unsigned int b0 and unsigned int b1 are not constexpr
You can do what compiler tells you to do, finish constexpr declaration: static constexpr A::B emptyStaticConstexpr {.b0=10,.b1=11};

but 10 and 11, the initialisers, are ... is that not relevant?


You can do what compiler tells you to do,

But I don't want to specify them again, that would be duplicated code.

that is initialized at runtime, not at compile time as constexpr requires

If you're not already working on it, @Gene , formally write this one up. I can see this misconception tripping up a lot of future programmers.

@ewrhuwaereww -- don't nest struct B in class A, take it outside, so it's complete, then it will work

@user4581301 -- I'm not writing an answer, not sufficiently versed in the standard

Seems like this might be the open bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88165. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408962/try-to-understand-compiler-error-message-default-member-initializer-required-be,

@Nick Matteo -- looks like that, clang/gcc want the class to be complete, MSVC is fine with in-class initialization.

@Gene don't nest  << but why does it not work if it's nested as it is? Type B is complete by the time I define the constexpr. If it was an issue with b0 and b1 not being constexpr, then it should still be an issue when they are not nested.

@Gene It has nothing to do with whether or not b0 and b1 are constexpr (which they can't be because they are non-static data members). There is also no issue in using the default member initializers in a constant expression. The reason that the compiler behaves the way it does is due to some unfortunate side effects of the implementation details required to implement the standard-mandated rules for name lookup in complete class context.

@Gene The default member initializers are complete-class contexts and, naively that means that the compiler can only fully understand them after the closing brace of the outer-most class definition containing them. Figuring out what exactly is supposed to compile or not in situations of this kind is a bit tricky.

@ewrhuwaereww "Type B is complete by the time I define the constexpr": Unfortunately, for the purpose of complete-class contexts lookup must (generally) be deferred until the end of the outer-most nested class definition. It is permitted to refer to names declared later in the containing class inside the default member initializers of the nested class. And therefore the compiler, generally, can't fully understand whether or not the default constructor of the nested class is implicitly defined and usable for the constant initialization. (Which doesn't mean that it should not work anyway.)

"This question is different from Try to understand compiler error message: default member initializer required before the end of its enclosing class" -- Only in an inconsequential detail -- "in that I am trying to instantiate a static constexpr while they were defining a default constructor for B and then trying to use the constructor as default parameter in a static method." -- More to the point, you are trying to use the default constructor (for something valid), while they were trying to use the default constructor (for something valid).

To clarify "Only in an inconsequential detail": I mean "inconsequential" with regards to answers. Someone asking would not be expected to know that the difference is inconsequential, hence this question can serve "as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question."
