# Default member initializer needed within definition of enclosing class outside of member functions

Tags: c++

very simple example having nested structures and a method with defaulted value

```
struct outer {
    struct inner
    {
        int x{0};
    };

    void foo(inner = inner())
    {}
};
```

compiling with clang and gcc8 both return this error

```
main.cpp:7:22: error: default member initializer for 'x' needed within definition of enclosing class 'outer' outside of member functions

    void foo(inner = inner())

                     ^

main.cpp:4:13: note: default member initializer declared here

        int x{0};

            ^

1 error generated.
```

example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f28eb47735bfa4e5

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819314/default-member-initializer-needed-within-definition-of-enclosing-class-outside) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866686/default-member-initializer-needed-within-definition-of-enclosing-class-outside) but still have no idea what's going on?

Comment: ups, fixed, thx

Comment: duplicate #2 doesn't much answer this question, but the #1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408962/try-to-understand-compiler-error-message-default-member-initializer-required-be
seems legit, it's a compiler bug, thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why this is not allowed.
I can produce a workaround thus using overload:

```
void foo(inner)
{}
void foo() {
    foo(inner());
}
```

If someone can tell what is the difference (from the type system point of view) between overloading a function and providing a default value, that information may contain the reason why the language doesn't allow the pattern specified in the question