# c++17: inner class default member initializer ignored in static inline varilables

Tags: c++, inner-classes

Compiling it using `clang -std=c++17`, and the error msg is `default member initializer for '_x' needed within definition of enclosing class 'A' outside of member functions`.
I tried it with gcc, and got the same error msg.

It's not obvious to me why it's disallowed, and it seems that once I move the inner struct outside the enclosing class (move B out of A), it compiles fine.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
struct B {
  size_t _x = 0;
};
  private:
    static inline B b = {};
};

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It compiles fine using MS compiler. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819314/default-member-initializer-needed-within-definition-of-enclosing-class-outside

Comment: Interestingly `static inline B b = {42};` compiles, it's just the `{ }` version that doesn't.